# WordPress Custom Search Button

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I got a custom search form in my WordPress Blog, i have this search code in my sidebar inside a text widget.

```
        <div class="search-form">
          <input type="text" value="" class="input-txt" id="search-txt"/>
          <input type="submit" value="Search" class="input-btn" id="idsubmit" onClick="search_redirect()"/>
          <script type="text/javascript">
              function search_redirect(){
                 text_val = document.getElementById('search-txt').value;
                 if(text_val!=''){
                   url_re = 'http://bizisearch.com/search?page=1&limit=20&engine=spider&type=web&query='+'"'+text_val+'"';
                     window.location = url_re;
                   } else {
                     alert('search input is required');
                   }
                   }    

   window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById('testfield').onkeypress = function(e){
   if (!e) e = window.event;
   var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if (keyCode == '13'){
     search_redirect();
     return false;
     }
    }
   }                            
            </script> 
        </div>
```

I want the search results to "OPEN IN A NEW TAB" and i can press the "ENTER" key to search....

Is there a tutorial or can you guide me on how to do that???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control how to open in a new tab.
The enter can be accomplished by capturing a click event on your enter key and call your function in that event.

Enter event in JQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.input-btn').keydown(function (e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
             search_redirect();
        }
    })
});
```

Make sure you include JQuery if it is not included:

or follow [this guide](http://matthewruddy.com/using-jquery-with-wordpress/) to include it a better way.

In pure Javascript: (you should give your button an id)

```
window.onload = function(){
   document.getElementById('testfield').onkeypress = function(e){
       if (!e) e = window.event;
       var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
       if (keyCode == '13'){
         search_redirect();
         return false;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the code for the ENTER function.. I'm not good with javascript i just got this code from the MAIN site.

Comment: I updated my answer with a JQuery version and a pure Javascript solution. If you are using JQuery I would recommend using the above function.

Comment: the above code still not working :(  not sure where to place the codes you have posted..

Comment: It should work. The pure Javascript code example has to be between your script tags. When using JQuery, make sure JQuery is loaded.

Comment: jQuery is already loaded because my sliders are working.. anyway, i tried the pure java script code. Please see the code if it's correct.

Comment: If you have placed the Javascript code in your head it is possible the element is not known yet, try wrapping it with window.onload (I edited the example).  The JQuery should also work.  Please provide more details like errors when it is not working.  This makes it easier to help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33122/discussion-between-jeremi-liwanag-and-randomizer)